# Finding integers whose sum of digits equals the sum of the digits of a multiple of them

Tags: nt.number-theory

For a given integer $x>0$, I need to find all integers $a \in [0, 10^{15}]$ which have the following property: the digit sum of $a$ equals the digit sum of $x\cdot a$.

I found this link http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CastingOutNines.html which looks quite relevant to my task, but I can't figure out how to apply it.

Any ideas?

Comment: For this tiny range you may simply program verification of the property.

Comment: Wouldn't $a_1=1$, $x=10$ work? Also, where do the $a_2,\ldots,a_n$ come in? Presumably, you meant that the digit sum of $a_i$ is equal to the digit sum of $x\cdot a_{i-1}$. However, I'm not sure this is appropriate for MO, please see the FAQ http://mathoverflow.net/faq#whatnot for a list of some other sites for which your question may be better suited.

Comment: Can't you take $x=10$ for all $a$'s? I guess I do not understand the problem...

Comment: The problem is: For a given integer $x>0$, find all numbers $a$ in the range such that the digit sums of $a$ and $xa$ coincide.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Wadim, it makes much more sense now.

Comment: thanks for clarification. I probably didn't explain it properly. Range doesn't matter, it's much bigger and brute force won't help (my code is already running for 3 days). So, I decided to look for more reasonable solution...

Comment: @Jull: It could be nice if you edit your problem more. If you wish to get the property $S(a)=S(xa)$ valid *for all* $x>0$. Then there are no such numbers. Indeed, if $a$ exists, then concantination $\overline{aa}=a\cdot$ with $x=10^n+1$ gives you a number with sum of digits twice more than $S(a)$. If you mean a fixed given $x$, then you can reduce your check using the fact that $S(a)$ and $a$ have the same residue modulo 9, so that $ax$ and $x$ has to be congruent modulo 9.

Comment: @Yemon: The problem is still trivial. What was the edit?!

Comment: @Wadim: I just removed a tag that didn't belong there

Comment: @Yemon: Allright. I still hope that the author is interested in explaining what's the problem is about. Maybe, even what it's for.

Comment: The list of integers $a$ such that the digit sums of $a$ and $7a$ are equal begins with $3,6,9,15,18,30,33,36,39,45,48,60,63\dots$. Neither this sequence, nor the one you get by dividing each term by three, is in the OEIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to get the property $S(a)=S(xa)$ (where $S(\cdot)$ denotes the sum of decimal digits) valid for all positive integers $x$, then there are no such numbers $a$. Indeed, if such an $a$ existed, then concantination $\overline{aa}=a\cdot x$ with $x=10^n+1$, $n$ the number of digits in $a$, would give you a number $xa$ with sum of digits twice more than $S(a)$.

I put the answer because my comments on clarifying the problem were ignored.

Answer (score 2):

@Wadim Zudilin: Indeed. It looks like a problem from the [Euler project](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems).

Comment: Thanks for the link. It's a treasury for puzzling students in elementary computational number theory.