#  Taming this Conway-type sequence

Tags: nt.number-theory, sequences-and-series, reference-request

(I started working on this problem after trying to get any "interesting" pattern out of the number that Gowers randomly wrote while answering:[What is realistic mathematics?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34843/what-is-realistic-mathematics).)

The number was 123871205412470874297947938271423698765734564756028492656.

Take any number, for instance:

> 123871205412470874297947938271423698765734564756028492656
>
> 3484756955 (in the preceding number there are three 0's, four 1's,..., and finally five 9's)
>
> 0001231111  (in the preceding number there are no 0's, no 1's,..., and finally one 9)
>
> 3511000000
>
> 6201010000
>
> .... clearly the list won't end as there will always be some no 0's or 1's or 2's, etc.

A variant of this sequence is discussed [here(Conway's look-and-say sequence)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/27324/what-are-some-naturally-occurring-high-degree-polynomials).

This a fairly simple obsevation, so is there a literature about such sequences from which I can learn more?

Comment: The 5th number above should be 6201010000. Then 6210001000. And then it's constant. 

Comment: The reason for downvotes? I'm not a puzzle fan and I also do not want MO to become a numerology site as Wadim Zudilin pointed to me here :http://mathoverflow.net/questions/27922/ethio-integers


Comment: @Thanks. So, I'm still experimenting. This number is one of those which culminate with a constant.

Comment: It doesn't sound like you think Gowers wrote a random number?  That there was some hidden code in it?

Comment:   e.g. 1->0100000000->9100000000->8100000001->....->6201001000->6210001000 So, 1 culminates in 6210001000. Maybe all numbers end at this number, any heuristics?

Comment: @ Rob, no I did not think that way. Had I, I would have phrased my question as "...the number that Gowers might have cryptically written..." and I wouldn't have said "...randomly..." Let's not extrapolate on such matters but look for some beauty in the numbers, please.

Comment: You might try to think about a more informative title ...

Comment: @Tom, thanks. Similar to Kevin Buzzard's previous post:http://mathoverflow.net/questions/23593/open-project-lets-compute-the-fourier-expansion-of-a-non-solvable-algebraic-maa  I'm now calling for a collaborative project.

Comment: What convention do you choose when the initial number has more than 9 copies of a digit?

Comment: Sorry, giving a downvote.  I think projects like these on MO need to be *extremely* well thought out, and contain significant mathematical content and motivation.  

Comment: @ Scott, no trimming, no change, just concatenate as they appear.  

Comment: As long as your convention is reasonable, you only need to iterate over partitions of 10, and there are only 42 of these.

Comment: How is that it is 42, please?

Comment: @Cam McLeman, agreed.

Comment: After enough steps, you will always end up with a 10 digit sequence whose numbers add up to 10.  There are 42 ways to break up the number 10 as an unordered sum of positive integers, so without loss of generality, you can restrict your initial conditions to the digit sequences describing these 42 partitions.

Comment: Scott, the heuristics for "you will always end up with a 10 digit sequence whose numbers add up to 10" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to be a bit more precise - for instance what happens if there are more than nine of a particular digit ? Regardless, a cursory literature search comes up with
[an article](http://www.jstor.org/pss/2974579) by Sauerberg and Shu which studies the Conway sequence as well as ones similar to yours, which are called factor-free counting sequences. The final section shows they are eventually periodic and gives a list of all possible cycles.

In particular, when counting the digits 0,1,...,9 as in the question, one ends up either at the fixed point 6210001000 or at the 2-cycle 6300000100-->7101001000.